# Powershell to get the list of disabled users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm running this command to get the list of all the disable users but it'S not working

```
Get-ADUser -Filter (enabled -ne $true)
```

Here is the error message :

```
The term 'enabled' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was inc
luded, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:28
+ Get-ADUser -Filter (enabled <<<<  -ne $true)
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (enabled:String) [], CommandNotF
   oundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a scriptblock to define the filter. The parantheses are used for "groups" to make sure that the expression inside it invoked before running the cmdlet, which is wrong here as `enabled` doesn't mean anything to powershell by itself.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter { enabled -ne $true }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Search-ADAccount` cmdlet has a parameter just for that:

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled
```